# iOS 7 Access iPhone camera from Mobile Safari?

Tags: html, input, camera, mobile-safari, ios7

In **iOS 6** you could use something like this:

```
<input type="file" accept="image/*" capture="camera">
<input type="file" accept="video/*" capture="camera">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GAbW8/embedded/result/

But in **iOS 7**  you cannot access the camera anymore. Ideas?

Comment: This worked for me on iOS 6  and iOS 7.0.2 on an iPhone 4s.

Comment: This worked for me on iOS 7.1 on an iPhone 5.

Comment: Retested this on iOS 7.0.4. It works! I may have tested this only in Simulator back then, where there is no camera is available. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: works for me; on iOS6, iPhone 4

Answer (score -1):

Please try this:

```
...type="file" accept="image/*" capture>
```