# Web application Javascript to process the stream of information from iOS device camera (NOT an APP!)

Tags: javascript, ios, html, web, camera

I am Looking to scan barcode from iOS devices (most likely using safari/ HTML5). I wanted to know if its possible to stream the content from camera till the script recognizes the barcode.

I know there are scripts (i have seen JSfiddle) that helps in capturing and uploading images. But I do not want to upload images. All I want to do is use the camera in my webpage to scan the bar code.

I want to know if this is even possible ? ( I searched and I found not a single website that does it, hence skeptical). Guess I made my question clear and hoping its not a duplicate (I tried searching for this question too :( ]

Comment: For completion sake, can you also point to your JSfiddle link ? I'm curious to see how you would access the cam from JS

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19097127/ios-7-access-iphone-camera-from-mobile-safari) is the question. And he also provides a fiddle that worked on my iphone. It can access your camera/photo album to upload 1 image. Here is the link for the fiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/GAbW8/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 0):

You need the scan logic in javascript if you dont want to upload images.

Try and see if this works :

http://badassjs.com/post/654334959/barcode-scanning-in-javascript

Comment: I think this JS also requires an image and it does post processing of the image. This is cool too! but what i was requesting was for processing the data from the camera stream. from what I see, HTML5 allows developers to access hardware in many cases and was wondering if iOS is not allowing the access to camera for processing the stream of information. Thanks for the suggestion though ! I will keep looking for more answers and lets see if we have an answer from other experts here :)